# Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios

when I parse My json response 
and this my error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' (0x104bcd838) to 'NSDictionary' (0x104bcf818).

this is my code

```
@IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let parameters: Parameters=[

        "email":emailUser.text!,
        "password":passWord.text!,

        ]
    let url2 = "http://marwen1994.alwaysdata.net/Carpooling/public/loginpost.php"
    Alamofire.request(url2, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            let A = response.result.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>
          let list = A["items"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
            let nom = list["name"] as! String
            let pass = A["password"] as! String
            let email = list["email"] as! String
            let adresse = A["adresse"] as! String
            let DateNaissance = A["DateNaissance"] as! String
            let id = A["id"] as! Int
            let numTel = A["num_tel"] as! Int
            if(pass == self.passWord.text)
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ConnectionStatus")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "ConnectedID")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(nom, forKey: "nom")
               // UserDefaults.standard.set(prenom, forKey: "prenom")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(adresse, forKey: "adresse")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(pass, forKey: "motDePasse")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(numTel, forKey: "numTel")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(DateNaissance, forKey: "DateNaissance")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfile", sender: nil)
            }
            else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Woah!!!", message: "You inserted a wrong email or a wrong password! Please enter a valid mail and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty obvious isn't it? `let A = response.result.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>`. What does the json response look like?

Comment: {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "unique_id": "5bb7682e2031f7.15799495",
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "encrypted_password": "5hQXusqX1GyyMO5ZvOrvJbkHvFMxOTQwYmYwM2Ew",
            "salt": "1940bf03a0",
            "created_at": "2018-10-05 15:33:34",
            "updated_at": null,
            "num_tel": "+21695502248",
            "image": "14",
            "adresse": "tunis-ariana",
            "DateNaissance": "12/14/2018"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: So, `A["items"]` is an array that contains a dictionary rather than a dictionary itself.  In general, don't use `!` unless you **really** know what the correct type will be.

Comment: (Learn to) **read** the JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only 2 (two) collection types: `[]` is array (Swift `[[String:Any]]` or `[Dictionary<String,Any>]`), `{}` is dictionary (Swift `[String:Any]` or `Dictionary<String,Any>`).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know where the error is without seeing the actual JSON response, but probably this is an Array and not a Dictionary

```
let list = A["items"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
```

Should be something like

```
let list = A["items"] as! Array
```

Comment: {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "unique_id": "5bb7682e2031f7.15799495",
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "encrypted_password": "5hQXusqX1GyyMO5ZvOrvJbkHvFMxOTQwYmYwM2Ew",
            "salt": "1940bf03a0",
            "created_at": "2018-10-05 15:33:34",
            "updated_at": null,
            "num_tel": "+21695502248",
            "image": "14",
            "adresse": "tunis-ariana",
            "DateNaissance": "12/14/2018"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: this the JSOn response

Comment: so yeah, what I said, items is an array, not a dictionary, as it only has one element you can do `let list = A["items"][0] as!  as! Dictionary<String,Any>`, but if you manage the server and it will only return an item I would change it to return the object (dictionary) instead of the array. Also is not good that you return the password to the app

Answer (score 0):

If you could consider using `Codable` this might help

```
struct JsonResponse: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let encrypted_password: String
    let num_tel: String
    let adresse: String
    let DateNaissance: String
}
```

The actual decoding is done like this

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let jsonResponse = try decoder.decode(JsonResponse.self, from: data)

    for item in jsonResponse.items {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(item.name, forKey: "nom")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(item.email, forKey: "email")
        //and so on
    }
} catch {
    print("Decode error: \(error)")
}
```

`data` is the json message in `response`, I don't know how Alamofire works so you need to figure out yourself how to access it correctly.

---

There is an array inside "items" with a single element, access it like

```
if let A = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>, let list = A["items"][0] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {

}
```

Comment: this is my jsonresponse

Comment: {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "unique_id": "5bb7682e2031f7.15799495",
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "encrypted_password": "5hQXusqX1GyyMO5ZvOrvJbkHvFMxOTQwYmYwM2Ew",
            "salt": "1940bf03a0",
            "created_at": "2018-10-05 15:33:34",
            "updated_at": null,
            "num_tel": "+21695502248",
            "image": "14",
            "adresse": "tunis-ariana",
            "DateNaissance": "12/14/2018"
        }
    ]
}